# Using PIVOT and Group By to Aggregate histograms?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, pivot-table

I have a table in SQL server that contains a lot of 2d histograms (each histogram contains 32 index and values) as follows:

[image]

These histograms are logged in a time series which means in each specific date we have a histogram with a unique ID. I want to get the average of these histograms --weekly--. It means for each week  of a month (if there is a data in that week), I want to have one histogram for each unique ID. Then I want to convert these two 2d histograms into 1d. At the end my desired table should have one row for each unique ID that contains the value of histogram.  As an example, I would like to have the below table at the end:

```
   ID             Date (year), Month , week , index1 , index2,  ... , Index31 , Index32
   273854048        2019     ,   4   ,  1   ,   23   ,  234  ,  ... ,    0    ,  95.00
   287092805        2019     ,   4   ,  4   ,   0.0  ,  95.0 ,  ... ,    43   ,   64
   ...             ...
```

It seems PIVOT and group by should be used, but it seems very complicated.

Comment: Where are you looking to present or use the output of this query?  Can you not do the pivot within that tool using the data as in your snippet, which will likely be a lot easier than via SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple pivot clause should do the trick.

The columns will be `ID, Date, 1, 2, 3....`

```sql
SELECT pvt.*
FROM YourTable t
PIVOT (
    MIN(t.[Value]) FOR t.[Index] IN
      ([1]),([2]),([3]),([4]),([5]),([6]),([7]),([8]),([9]),([10]),([11]),([12]),([13]),([14]),([15]),([16]),([17]),([18]),([19]),([20]),([21]),([22]),([23]),([24]),([25]),([26]),([27]),([28]),([29]),([30]),([31]),([32])
) pvt
```

You can add a relevant `ORDER BY` if necessary